# Общий временной диапазон на графиках в Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Редактирую чужой код. 
Имеется скрипт с функциями, которые рисуют графики, в конце скрипта функция, которая вызывает эти функции и формирует единый отчет со всеми этими графиками. Графики строятся на основании xlsx-файлов так, что по оси ОХ откладывается время, а по оси ОY - какое-то другое поле таблицы. В полях есть пропуски.

Проблема в том, что Plotly масштабирует оси OX(времени) по имеющимся для того или иного поля  данным. В результате получается, что два соседних графика имеют имеют разные значения времени по OX и приходится их неудобно масштабировать вручную:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача: Получать разные графики в одинаковом диапазоне значений ОХ.

Comment: Это совсем не похоже на минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример ;-) Тем кто захочет вам помочь придется перелопатить 19Kb чужого кода. Очевидно такие люди должны иметь много свободного времени и высокий уровень мотивации :)

Comment: Попробую декомпозировать до приемлемого размера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял вопрос, то вы можете использовать довольно простое решение:
раз уж вы все равно читаете данные из файлов Excel, то загружайте их сразу в дейтафремы `pandas` так, чтобы во всех дейтафреймах был столбец даты с одинаковым названием, а столбцы со значениями имели разное название:

```
df1:
         Date  Value1
0  2019-02-15     200
1  2019-03-15     180
2  2019-05-15     185
3  2019-06-15     117
4  2019-10-15     200

df2:
         Date  Value2
0  2019-01-15     200
1  2019-05-15     180
2  2019-09-15     185
3  2019-10-15     117
4  2019-12-15     200
```

Как видно, в обоих df есть совпадающие даты и не совпадающие.
Остается их объединить таким образом:

```
merged = pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2, how='outer')

         Date  Value1  Value2
0  2019-02-15   200.0     NaN
1  2019-03-15   180.0     NaN
2  2019-05-15   185.0   180.0
3  2019-06-15   117.0     NaN
4  2019-10-15   200.0   117.0
5  2019-01-15     NaN   200.0
6  2019-09-15     NaN   185.0
7  2019-12-15     NaN   200.0
```

и рисовать график уже на основании данных из общего дейтафрейма (merged)

В конечном итоге, из двух отдельных графиков с разным масштабом по оси абсцисс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получим два графика с одинаковым масштабом, построенных на основании единого df (merged):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и очевидно, что ничто не мешает вам на основании общего df строить несколько графиком на одном холсте, раз уж масштаб по оси x у них одинаковый^

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Если нужно интерполировать даты, то можно воспользоваться таким способом:

Имеем:

```
df1
         Date  Value1
0  2019-02-15     200
1  2019-03-15     180
2  2019-05-15     185
3  2019-06-15     117
4  2019-10-15     200

df2

         Date  Value2
0  2019-01-15     200
1  2019-05-15     180
2  2019-09-15     185
3  2019-10-15     117
4  2019-12-15     200
5  2020-02-15     200
```

и общий:

```
     Date  Value1  Value2
0  2019-02-15   200.0     NaN
1  2019-03-15   180.0     NaN
2  2019-05-15   185.0   180.0
3  2019-06-15   117.0     NaN
4  2019-10-15   200.0   117.0
5  2019-01-15     NaN   200.0
6  2019-09-15     NaN   185.0
7  2019-12-15     NaN   200.0
8  2020-02-15     NaN   200.0
```

используем метод resample:

```
merged['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['Date'])
merged.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(merged['Date']), inplace=True, drop=True)
merged = merged.resample('SM').mean() #интерполируем. шаг в пол-месяца, для простоты.
```

Получаем:

```
           Value1  Value2
Date                      
2019-01-15     NaN   200.0
2019-01-31     NaN     NaN
2019-02-15   200.0     NaN
2019-02-28     NaN     NaN
2019-03-15   180.0     NaN
2019-03-31     NaN     NaN
2019-04-15     NaN     NaN
2019-04-30     NaN     NaN
2019-05-15   185.0   180.0
2019-05-31     NaN     NaN
2019-06-15   117.0     NaN
2019-06-30     NaN     NaN
2019-07-15     NaN     NaN
2019-07-31     NaN     NaN
2019-08-15     NaN     NaN
2019-08-31     NaN     NaN
2019-09-15     NaN   185.0
2019-09-30     NaN     NaN
2019-10-15   200.0   117.0
2019-10-31     NaN     NaN
2019-11-15     NaN     NaN
2019-11-30     NaN     NaN
2019-12-15     NaN   200.0
2019-12-31     NaN     NaN
2020-01-15     NaN     NaN
2020-01-31     NaN     NaN
2020-02-15     NaN   200.0
```

И у нас получается датасет с заполненными пробелами в датах.

Comment: Благодарю. Неожиданный подход, но рабочий

Comment: @StepanSokol По мне так это вообще очень удобный подход. Единственный нюанс, который приходит мне в голову - это необходимость интерполяции дат - добавления строк с датами и без значений в df, которые полностью отсутствуют в обоих дейтафреймах, так сказать для обеспечения континуума данных.

Comment: Да, именно этот момент и требуется, даже несмотря на то, что где-то на графике может получиться густо, где-то пусто